# Apache configuration for cloudControl w/ Symfony2 and Assetic?

Tags: apache, symfony, assetic, cloudcontrol

I'm having problems to show my generated assets in cloudControl. After `assetic:dump` the assets are created un the `/srv/www/code/web` folder but Apache is not accessing them.

This is my Apache configuration (`documentroot.conf`):

```
DocumentRoot /app/www/web

<Directory /app/www/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Options SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
    DirectoryIndex app.php

    FallbackResource /app.php
</Directory>
```

What is the correct Apache configuration to have Assetic working?

Also, can somebody explain me the difference between the `/srv/code`, the `~/www` (alias of the previous one) and `/app/www/web` **(the folder used in cloudControl examples for Apache config)**?

My guess was that the `/app/www` folder in the apache config was accessing `~/www` (and so, accessing `/srv/code`) but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was not in the folder used in the configuration. Both `/srv/www/code/web` and `/app/www/web` work the same (as they should, considering that `/app/www` is an alias of `/srv/www/www` which is an alias of `/srv/www/code`, as well explained by @TooAngel).

The problem was with the `assetic:dump` command, which for some reason, needs to be called during the build process.

I've added this to the `composer.json` file, and now it works:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php app/console cache:clear --env=prod",
            "php app/console assets:install --env=prod",
            "php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod"
         ],
         ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to get a better understanding of the 'insides' of a container, you can use the Secure Shell to connect to a container and see the actual directory structure. (https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#secure-shell-ssh)

- `/srv/www/code` is the actual directory where your application code is located
- `/srv/www/www` is a symlink to `/srv/www/code`, because of backward compatibility issues.
- `/app` is a symlink to `/srv/www`, to simplified the path and also to have compatiblity to other buildpacks and PaaS providers.
- `~/` is `/srv/www`, so from your example `~/www` points to the directory where you application is located.

If your assets are located in `/srv/www/code/web` you should be able to use:

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/code/web

<Directory /srv/www/code/web>
    AllowOverride All
    Options SymlinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
    DirectoryIndex app.php

    FallbackResource /app.php
</Directory>
```

I hope I covered all your cases and could clear up the situation?!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @TooAngel. But being aliases, they all work the same in the Apache configuration. Check my answer to see where I think where the problem is.